# PHP not allowing audio files (wav, mp3 etc) to be uploaded

Tags: php

I have been working on a **PHP** script which allows a user to upload an audio file. However, I noticed that audio files are never passed to the `$_FILES` super-global. If I use any other type of file type (ie. **jpeg** or **pdf**) it works fine.

I have tried:

- Increasing the cache size in the php.ini
- Increasing upload file size limit
- Increasing post max size limit
- Using a different directory
- Using `$_POST` instead of `$_FILES`

Here is the **PHP** (simplified):

```
if(isset($_FILES["userfile"]))
    var_dump($_FILES); // outputs when the file is a jpeg, png, pdf, psd etc.
else
    echo "No file uploaded"; // outputs when the file is ANY type of audio
```

and the **HTML** (simplified):

```
<form action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
    <input type="file" name="userfile">
    <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

I have no idea as to why **PHP** would not be passing an audio file to the `$_FILES` array, so all help is appreciated.

Cheers.

**UPDATE:**
After changing from **PHP** Version 7.2.1 to **PHP** Version 7.1.12, all audio files are successfully uploading. However, using **PHP** 7.1.12 causes my pages to all output the `headers already sent` error. <strike>Why must **PHP** be so annoying? :(</strike>

Comment: In which `php.ini` you've made changes? Could you post your `phpinfo()` dump?

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? Have you checked whether it works with a small audio file compared to a large PDF file (which means that your first examples triggered the upload size limit)? And is there really no message logged anywhere about this?

Comment: @GufranHasan why should this be a duplicate of the other question? That is clearly another problem as it uses `getimagesize`

Comment: @D.Dimitrov my PHP version is 7.2.1, which is the php.ini I changed

Comment: @NicoHaase My file limit is 150MB, and the audio file that I am uploading is just 2.5MB :) So I'm assuming it's within bounds haha

Comment: @NicoHaase, He is facing the same problem as he is not able to upload audio files.

Comment: @GufranHasan no, the problem is not the same, as the code from the other question uses `getimagesize` to calculate something, and the code from this question does not

Comment: @GufranHasan my problem is not even close to that. Their problem has to do with the fact they are using an incorrect function to check file size. My problem has to do with the fact PHP does not accept the audio file in it's entirety. Please remove your flag.

Comment: Your code is working on my server. Dump of `$_FILES` -> `array(1) { ["userfile"]=> array(5) { ["name"]=> string(27) "Windows Feed Discovered.wav" ["type"]=> string(9) "audio/wav" ["tmp_name"]=> string(14) "/tmp/php6xx4E6" ["error"]=> int(0) ["size"]=> int(19884) } }`

Comment: I'll join others and say that something is wrong in php.ini file. Maybe the one you changed is not the one that is used? That is possible. I just checked the same form and everything works like a charm

Comment: Still, what have you tried to debug the problem? Have you used a higher error reporting level, have you had a look at the server's error log?

Comment: Check your `Loaded Configuration File` from `phpinfo();`. Is that the file you've changed?

Comment: @D.Dimitrov sure is the file I changed :)

Comment: And you don't want to provide some more information such that we could help you?

Comment: About your last update: maybe it was a previous change in PHP configuration that prevented you to upload these files, and changing version restored initial settings, allowing it to work? For the `headers already sent`, it's probably simply your debug display that causes that (placed before sending headers)